# How can I set a readonly property value using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

For testing, I need to set the value of a readonly property. Here's my code:

```
public void SetPrivatePropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propName, T val)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    var prop = t.GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (prop == null)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propName", string.Format("Property {0} was not found in Type {1}", propName, obj.GetType().FullName));
    t.InvokeMember(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, obj, new object[] { val });
}
```

but it's giving me an error like:

```
Method '<methodName>' not found
```

I also tried with

```
prop.SetValue(obj, true, null);
```

but then the error is:

```
Property set method not found
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: The property has no set method, so you can not invoke it.

Comment: There must be some backing field for readonly property with no setter otherwise CLR also will not be able to set it's value. Right?

how can I find that backing field?

Comment: A property in .Net metadata is basically only a reference to up to 3 methods (.get, .set, .other) and its not safe to assume that every property has a backing field; Just imagine `int Prop { get { return 1; } }` or a method with a more complex getter method. When you know there is a backing field and no more operations in the getter that involve a field you could get the getter method `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()`, parse the IL instructions `MethodBase.GetILAsByteArray()`, search for a `stfld/stsfld opcode` and then resolve its token `Module.ResolveField()` to get your FieldInfo object.